# 7zip command line options for more information when synchronizing

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, command-line-arguments

In the 7zip command line options, is there some argument that can make 7z output the files ignored/deleted from the archive too? (files ignored by the option `-uq0`)

Example call:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u "C:\Docz.7z" -uq0 "C:\Documentsx\*"
```

7zip Verbose:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Scanning
Updating archive C:\Docz.7z
Compressing hello.txt
Everything is Ok
```

If the archive is added or replaced it says "Compressing hello.txt"

I would like to get more info or verbose...something like this:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Scanning
Updating archive C:\Docz.7z
Updating hello.txt
Adding   examplenew.txt
Deleting/Ignoring documentdeleted.txt
Everything is Ok
```

Answer (score 6):

7zip does not have "extra verbosity" option. But you could use [7zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) and write a simple wrapper around the library to do what you want.

Comment: Not factible right now. It would have to be developed and maintained throught future 7zip versions and so on (We dont have the resources for this option) :S

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need that? I mean, the `-u` flag is precisely designed to have a fine grained control over the archive update.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ms=off -uq0 u "C:\Docz.7z" "C:\Documentsx\*"
```

will update `Docz.7z` adding and deleting files provided you created the archive with the `-ms=off` switch (otherwise you won't be able to delete files). If you ever need to compare what you have in `C:\Documentsx\` with what there is in the archive, you'll have either to write a wrapper as said by Alex P., or write script with whatever you want to do the comparison between the list of files in `C:\Documentsx\` and the output of `7z l Docz.7z`.

For instance, using the command line under Linux (which can be transformed into a script):

```
7z l Docz.7z | cut -c54-80 | sed -n -E '/---/,/---/p' | sed '/---/d' | sort > Docz.list
ls Documents/* | sort > Documents.list
diff Docz.list Documents.list
```

I know you don't use Linux, but you can use that bash script as a basis for your own.

But could you tell us a bit more about the background and about what you try to achieve? You might have chosen a wrong path...

Comment: We use this command to sincronize a folder to a .zip file that will be included in an exe application. This command is called from visual studio prebuild command option... The idea was to get a litte more info of the changes since the last exe build at a glance: files adds, files updated, files deleted... 

Internally 7zip knows this already when running with the file sync/update flag, we only need it to show this info to us...

Comment: Please don't get me the wrong way, but isn't that one of the most useful feature of a *version control system*? Tracking files... If you are using a prebuild command, why don't you use such a script to get the diff? If the number of files is reasonably small, you can also call `7z l Docz.7z` right before the update and right after. But once again, I don't really see the point. But if you really want it this way, just make a patch and submit it. I don't think 7zip folks would turn it down.

Comment: We only needed it as extra information when compiling, so its not so important as to using a vcs or developing an extra script for that info...We added it as suggestion in the 7zip issue tracker so wish us luck ^^

Answer (score 0):

7z has kind of a verbose option "-bbX" where X is [0..3], maximum verbosity is "-bb3", and then there's "-slt" (show technical information). At least Linux version, but I suppose Windows version has that too? though that's by far not as verbose as Linux's "xz" with "-vvv".